# jQuery one event prevents other event from being fired

Tags: jquery, event-handling, listener, jquery-events

I'm unsure about what I am overlooking. If my design is just bad or if there is a smart way of solving this.

Given:
1 input field
1 hidden button

Logic:
If the input field is focused, the hidden button gets shown.
If the input field is unfocused, the button gets hidden.
If the button is clicked, some function is called, and then the button gets hidden.

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the input field gets unfocused just before, so the `unfocus` listener fires first and somehow the button-click listener never fires.

Why is this? Why aren't both listeners triggered?

Current code structure:

```
$(someinputfield).focus(function(){
    show button
}
$(someinputfield).focusout(function(){
    hide button
}
$(somebutton).click(function(){
    deliver();
    hide button
}
```

`deliver();` never gets executed!

Edit:
Here the real code:

```
      $("#input1").focus(function(){
          $("#submit1").delay(600).queue(function(next){
              $(this).css('display', 'block');
              next();
          });
      });
      $("#input1").focusout(function(){
          $("#submit1").hide();
      });
      $("#submit1").click(function(){
          deliver();
          setTimeout(function(){
              $(this).hide();
          }, 2000);
      });
```

Comment: I'm guessing this button is like a "remove text" button?
Can you show your code related to this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/2cjmggqe/ Works fine here

Comment: I guess click event as no time to be fired. You could use instead mousedown event or better, set the focus/blur logic to any common container parent

Comment: @JoshStevenson Doesn't here: https://jsfiddle.net/2cjmggqe/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff thats because you changed the fade to hide and show, which is instant. To get it to work with that you would need to listen to a `mouseover` on the button to prevent the input losing focus causing the button to dissappear on click

Comment: @JoshStevenson Ya but anyway OP has to post relevant code in question itself, not this useless pseudo code

Comment: ok, apparently a click takes 100 miliseconds. https://jsfiddle.net/2cjmggqe/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `input` instead of `button` for the button.

that way the input will remain focus when you click on the button, but not outside.

> Your selector for the `.focus()` event will have to include both the input and it's button, in my example below I have simply selected ALL inputs. You will need to change this.

```
$(function(){

    $('input').focus(function(){
        $('.button').show();
    });

    $('input').blur(function(){
        $('.button').hide();
    });

    $('.button').click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });

});
```

**JSFiddle here** http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/2cjmggqe/2/

Comment: I like the idea of making it both input fields with the same class, thus never losing focus. Another way is delaying the focusout hide for 100miliseconds. That's the time the click needs, at least in my browser.

Comment: Yeah delaying it is a good idea, but it's just more effort isn't it lol :)